# Why are there extra characters in my char[]?

Tags: arrays, c, char, reverse, chararray

I,m trying to shorten a char[] by a specified number, and for some reason, I've got more characters in my new char[]. Can you help me fix this?

When I tried with 1 or 2 letters, the result is this:
(the d, n, k, a are the first letters of each lines reversed)
`@▬w @▬n @▬k @▬a`

(the di, an, ok, la are the first two letters of each lines reversed)
`@id @an @ok @la`

With 3 letters, it works perfectly:
`nid ran rok mla`

But same problem with more than 3:
`qp░nnid qp░aran qp░trok qp░amla` 
And with more letters than the longest line, it also works perfectly:

`eynnid scnaran etrok amla`  
<--- These are my words backwards --->

```
char **read(FILE *file, int lineLength, int *pLines)
{
    size_t total = 0;
    size_t allocated = START;

    int sor = 0;

    char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];
    char shortened[lineLength];
/////////
    //printf("%d", sizeof(shortened));
    char **lines= (char **)malloc(allocated* sizeof(char *));

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LENGTH, file) != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
        {
            shortened[i] = buffer[i];
        }

        int length = strlen(shortened);
        if (shortened[length - 1] == '\n')
        {
            shortened[length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        if (line == allocated)
        {
            allocated*= 2;
            lines= realloc(sorok, allocated* sizeof(char *));
        }
        lines[line] = (char *)malloc(lineLength);

        strcpy(lines[line], shortened);
        line++;
    }
    *pLines = line;
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Why not read directly into `shortened`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You never declared the variable `line`.

Comment: What is `sorok` in the `realloc()` expression??

Comment: @Barmar Thinking `sor` means `line` and `sorok` means `lines`... Incomplete translation for the benefit of SO readers, perhaps?

Comment: I don't see the point of `shortened`.  Just read into the buffer, then write a string terminator either at index `lineLength - 1` (assumed less than `MAX_LENGTH`) or at the location of the first newline, whichever is earlier.  Then use `buffer` instead of `shortened`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major problem is this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
{
    shortened[i] = buffer[i];
}
```

If `lineLength > strlen(buffer)` then you will copy the null-terminator (and beyond, including data that isn't initialized by the `fgets` call).

***But*** if `strlen(buffer) >= lineLength` you will *not* copy the null-terminator. Then you use the `strlen` function on `shortened` which will then go beyond the end of `shortened` and you will have *undefined behavior*.

---

And for a better way to remove the newline (which you need to do for `buffer` and not `shortened`) see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)